# How to click on the 'Next page' generated by node/angular script button using webdriver for chrome?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am trying to scrape data from a website that returns results from a search criteria that spans into multiple pages... using Selenium, beautifulsoup on Python.  first page is easy to read.  Moving to next page requires to click on the '>' button.    The element looks like this:

```
<a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" class="ng-binding">Next
```

I tried the following:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get ("https:www....com/search/?lat=dfdfd  ")
page = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
# scraping the first page
#now need to click on the ">" , so that it can take me to the next page
```

Control should go to the next page, so that I can scrape.  There are 
    about 250 pages from these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, if you right-click the page, in the context menu there will be an option called "inspect". Click that and find the element in the html. Once you find it, right click it and go Copy > Copy XPath. You can then use the `browser.find_element_by_xpath` method to assign that element to a variable. You can then use `element.click()` to click it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how you don't has provide the URL, I'll show an example to solve this.

I'm considering the button has an ID, but you can change to find by a class, etc.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = Chrome()
browser.get("https:www....com/search/?lat=dfdfd  ")
page = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'next-button')))
# Next page
browser.find_element_by_id('next-button').click()

# Continuous your code ...
```